# Should MVC models contain content just for the response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a quiz style MVC application. I'm currently passing in to the view:

```
public class Question{
    public int QuestionId;
    public string QuestionText;
    public string AnswerText;
    public int Answer;
}
```

however all in the response I only need (and get) the two int properties, with null string values. So my question is, do you think my model should just contain the two int Properties and I should pass in the string properties in the `ViewData/ViewBag`?

Comment: Have a look at viewmodels. If your application is not a complex one, using ViewData/ViewBag is also fine. However, do not expose your Question model to view directly. It is dangerous.

Comment: Did the below suggestions help you ?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, yes, I believe it should. In this case I would create an `Answer` class that gets returned from the view and just contains the 2 int properties that you are interested in:

```
public class Answer{
    public int QuestionId;
    public int Answer;
}
```

Your controller action that receives this can accept a parameter of type `Answer`, which model binding will correctly populate. If you don't need the string properties to be returned from the view, don't pass them across. If you do need them, add them to the `Answer` class. There's no need to use ViewData or ViewBag for this at all. I would also rename them to `QuestionViewModel` and `AnswerViewModel` as per @emre-nevayeshirazi's suggestion. I would then map these to their equivalent domain classes before passing them to the domain layer.

Answer (score 0):

Split the *View Models* like below

```
public class Question : QuestionAnswerId
{
    public int QuestionText;
    public int AnswerText;
}

public class QuestionAnswerId
{
    public int QuestionId;
    public int Answer;
}
```